# Best way to enumurate the following directories and files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string, directory

I have bunch of directories at a certain paths in the following possible format:

```
C:\Program Files\Logic\DDC[ 0 ]

C:\Program Files\Logic\DDC[ 1]

C:\Program Files\Logic\DDC[2    ]

C:\Program Files\Logic\DDC[3]
```

I'd like to accomplish the following:

1)Enumurate all of numbered DDC directories and store their paths them in a List of String

```
I.E: List<String> ddcPaths -> should have:
ddcPaths[0] = "DDC[0]";
ddcPaths[1] = "DDC[1]";
ddcPaths[2] = "DDC[2]";
```

2)Enumurate all files directly under the DDC folder but nothing deeper than that

```
I.E: If DDC[0] has a.txt, b.txt and obj\c.txt, I should get
List<String> ddc_0 -> should have
ddc_0[0] = "a.txt";
ddc_0[1] = "b.txt";
```

I hope my explanation was clear enough but if something didn't make sense, please let me know.

Comment: So you want a list of directories matching a pattern, and for each directory you want another list of all the files directly under that directory but not recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If U have such data structure I suggest U should use one dictionary with directory name as key, and list of it's filenames as value. For example:

```
var ddcPaths = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var directoryInfo in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Logic\").GetDirectories())
{
    if (directoryInfo.Name.Contains("DDC["))
    {
         ddcPaths.Add(directoryInfo.Name, new List<string>());
         foreach (var fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
         {
             ddcPaths[directoryInfo.Name].Add(fileInfo.FullName);
         }
    }
}
```

but you should notice than U cant get Dictionary value by int index, only by key, declared in this dictionary (folder name in our case). But if U don't want to do like this U can do the following:

```
var ddcPaths = new List<string>();
var filePaths = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (var directoryInfo in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Logic\").GetDirectories())
{
   if (directoryInfo.Name.Contains("DDC["))
   {
       ddcPaths.Add(directoryInfo.Name);
       var tempList = new List<string>();
       foreach (var fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
       {
           tempList.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
       }
       filePaths.Add(tempList);
    }
}
```

but in this case U use two different data structures to represent related data. I suggest it would be logically to use dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DirectoryInfo`.

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("yourFolderPath");
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> subDirs = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories();

List<string> subDirsNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var subDir in subDirs)
 {
   subDirsNames.Add(subDir.Name.Trim());
   IEnumerable<string> files = subDir.EnumerateFiles().Select(i => i.Name);
   //do something with this list....
 }
```